# Laravel scheduler by supervisord running multiple time

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler, supervisord

I'm trying to use Supervisord with Laravel scheduler. It's working BUT running multiple times, I don't know whether any configuration is wrong. But what i expected is just one time for each scheduler. If i have any experience about this situation please help me.

1. This is supervisord conf file. *sudo nano /etc/supervisord.conf*

> ```
> [program:laravel-scheduler]
> client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipeum)02d
> command=php /var/www/project-api/artisan schedule:run --verbose --no-interaction
> [Process completed]autostart=true
> autorestart=true
> numprocs=1
> user=nginx
> redirect_stderr=true
> stdout_logfile=/var/www/project-api/storage/logs/schedule.log
> stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
> logfile_backups=10
> ```

2. This is laravel ConsoleKernel

> ```
> protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
> {
>     $schedule->command('telescope:prune --hours=24')->daily();
>     $schedule->command('horizon:snapshot')->everyFiveMinutes();
>     $schedule->job(new HourlyJob(), QueueName::HOURLY_JOB)->hourly();
>     $schedule->job(new MinuteJob(), QueueName::MINUTE_JOB)->everyTwoMinutes();
> }
> ```

3. This is the schedule.log file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdYn8.jpg)

The scheduler is correctly running every two minutes, but the problem is Running scheduled command multiple. Please help me this issue. Thank you

Comment: why are you using supervisor? this is what cron is for ... supervisor is to make sure something keeps running basically, which you would not want to happen (as it will just keep restarting it), you just want cron to hit the scheduler every minute

Comment: So you means that i just need to remove laravel-scheduler out of supervisord conf then everything will be okay, am i right ?

Comment: you should put the scheduler on cron not with supervisord. it was stated in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: no need of supervisor for cron jobs just schedule one cron on your cpanel which will hit schedule run every minute

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, after i put the scheduler on cron then it's running well, but it's $schedule->command. For $schedule->job case i could not see the jobs was pushed into queues. Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 8):

For schedule you should go for cronjob, you can use `crontab`

but if you insist to use `supervisor` follow me:

you should use `php artisan schedule:work` not `php artisan schedule:run` because the run command will run it just one time.

my supervisor configuration for the schedule is working well so I want to share it here:

```
[program:laravel-worker-nordicstandard-schedule]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
directory=/home/nordicstandard.net/
command=php artisan schedule:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= /home/nordicstandard.net/storage/logs/worker1.log
```

remember to use `directory=/home/nordicstandard.net/` to your project folder.

And that's it. it's working...

in `sudo supervisorctl` -> `status` you can see the output like:

```
laravel-worker-nordicstandard-schedule:laravel-worker-nordicstandard-schedule_00   RUNNING   pid 4084, uptime 0:06:55
```

and the last line is related to the `schedule` and the others are related to the `queue`.

note: you should be careful about `numprocs=1` and it shouldn't be more than one.

note2:
`php artisan schedule:listen` is like `php artisan schedule:work` but `php artisan schedule:listen` good for development, because it's listening to the latest changes in your code. but `php artisan schedule:work` will not consider your changes and uses the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem myself, and for me it turned out to be that supervisor was running cron in daemon mode (`-b`, also the default), and at the point it backgrounded supervisor thought it had exited so relaunched it. Supervisor repeated this four times before giving up, so we had four instances of cron running, and so four occurrences of each scheduled task. Running cron in foreground mode (`-f`) fixed it.